# Google +1 and Android not working?

Tags: android, google-plus-one

just bought a Samsung Galaxy II with Android, and by testing my website on it, I realised the Google +1 button is not showing up. I tried to reduce it to very problem, and ended up with this code :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>website mobile</title> 
    </head> 
<body> 
    <g:plusone></g:plusone>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I save it to my webserver and try to load in normal Android browser, the +1 button is not showing up. Is it normal, or am I doing something wrong ? This code works in normal browser (Google Chrome) as expected. I tried to use HTTPS or HTTP, both are working in browser, but none in Android.

Thanks for any advice.
  R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that google has it not running on mobile devices, as per Google employee here

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=35ecf072c7b70618&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if other people are having the same issue. Possibly contact Google about the question, or post in a Google discussion?

http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/4342089.htm

Comment: Thank you! I do not believe it is not working as both are google products, I guess I must have some setting wrong (phone maybe, its very new to me) ... I have seen the link you pasted, but there is no answer, i doubt this is comon problem, rather some settings somewhere :(