# Google Plus +1 not showing on IPhone

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-plus-one

Working example, see: http://www.samharris.org/site/full_text/faith-no-more/

```
<li><g:plusone size="medium" href="http://www.samharris.org/site/full_text/faith-no-more/"></g:plusone></li>

<!-- Place this tag after the last plusone tag -->
```

This displays fine in most browsers, but on the iPhone, the Plus One button doesn't display at all (see bottom of page).

There are no JS errors, and the code is correct according to Google's docs.

Ideas?

Comment: The same question was just asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866537/google-1-and-android-not-working/6866612#6866612 Hopefully it'll help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button now works on iPhone and Android browsers. See this announcement for more details: https://plus.google.com/111499908439497508351/posts/LWZuyUKFSao

Answer (score 2):

While the +1 button does work on mobile browsers now, on some iOS 5 devices it is possible that the button will not show up even though it appears to load correctly and even takes up (seemingly empty) space on the page.

If you ended up on this page because you are experiencing this issue, the fix is actually quite simple (and it has nothing to do with the way you added the plusone code to your page - you can experience the issue even on [Google's sample page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/)). All you need to do is go to `Settings > Safari > Clear Cookies and Data` on your iPhone and the button should display normally from then on.

Source: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=370463c6f9d1449b&hl=en&fid=370463c6f9d1449b0004b7709537ff3f

Answer (score 0):

The +1 Button does not support mobile browsers yet.